# Can I calculate stdev from a list of stdev values?

Tags: standard-deviation

I'm working with a list of performance metrics.  Each row represents some # of observations of one leg of the course/route/etc.  So each row/leg will have a best (time), worst, avg and stdev.

Adding together the best, worst and average values to get the course/route level totals makes intuitive sense to me, but I'm not so sure about stdev.

I don't have the individual data points, only the aggregated "per-leg" values.  Can I use the values I **do** have to calculate a valid stdev for the overall course/route?

Comment: Perhaps...if you have the sample size for each standard deviation reported.  ¿Is this information available?

Comment: @GreggH Yes, it'll be the same across legs.  So let's say it's always 5, how would that work?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the sample size for each group, then you can work the ANOVA summary table formulas backward to get the overall (aggregated sample) standard deviation.  Let $n_k$ be the sample size for each group and $N=\sum_{k=1}^K n_k$. I'll use $K$ for the number of groups (and all summations will be over $k=1$ to $k=K$.  I'll use $\bar x$ and $s$ as the sample means and standard deviations.  Lastly, $y$ will be the aggregate data set of interest.

1. Find the grand mean: $G = \frac{\sum n_k·\bar{x}_k}{\sum n_k}$
2. Find $SS_\text{between} = \sum n_k · (\bar{x}_k - G)^2$
3. Find $SS_\text{within} = \sum s_k^2·(n_k-1)$
4. Find $SS_\text{total} = SS_\text{between} + SS_\text{within}$
5. Find $MS_\text{total} = \text{Var}(y) = \frac{SS_\text{total}}{N-1}$
6. Take the square-root of this final value: $s_Y = \sqrt{MS_\text{total}}$

I hope this is useful in your analysis for your problem.

Comment: Amazing!! I will try to code this up in the next couple of days and see how far I get.  Much appreciated.

Comment: cool...please don't forget to vote up and/or accept the answers if you like them...cheers